# std::map::operator[] Violation access memory on windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio

I'm having a big issue on one of my project. This project is cross-platform. 
It works just fine on Linux, but on windows I have a Violation access memory when filling a map.

My main.cpp looks like this :

```
Server *s = new Server;

s->init(4253);
```

SERVER.CPP :

```
this->_commandManager.addFunction(C_CREATEROOM, &Server::createRoom);
this->_commandManager.addFunction(C_JOINROOM, &Server::joinRoom);
this->_commandManager.addFunction(C_LAUNCHGAME, &Server::createGame);
```

And finally my CommandManager :

```
bool CommandManager::addFunction(E_COMMAND type, bool (Server::*cmd)(ANetwork::t_frame frame, void *data))
{
  _commands[type] = cmd;

  return true;
}
```

_commands is type of `std::map<E_COMMAND, bool (Server::*)(ANetwork::t_frame, void*)>`

Adding cmd to _commands[type] works fine on Linux (ubuntu and opensuse) but throw a Violation Access Memory on Windows 10 with VS Entreprise 2015.

Comment: btw using all UPPERCASE for constants is antipattern

Comment: It's an enum. Not a constant

Comment: Does not matter, uppercase identifiers are used for macro (this way that habbit came from C to C++) and there is good chance your constant or enum would conflict, and in the best case you would get not obvious compilation error, in the worst hard to catch runtime one.

Comment: Oh ok thanks :) I did not know that ! I changed all my enum after seeing your comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS, try to use /vmg option in your compilator.